# CSS and JS not loading in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Not sure what is going on. I feel like it must be something internal with what I have in my gulpfile.js but not really sure. Code is identical to an example my Professor has shown.

This is what I have in app.js

```
alert(`JavaScript works!`);
```

This is what I have in index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title> Assignment #2 </title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <header>
    <h1>My First JavaScript Assignment</h1>
  </header>
  <main>
    <p>If you see/saw an alert box, the JavaScript works. If the background color is pink, then CSS works.</p>
  </main>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is what I have in style.css

```
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
body {
  background-color: cadetblue;
}
```

Comment: do you have your css file in a folder named css which is in the same folder as your html? Also, check the same for your js file.

Comment: Try use relative path to file adding `/` on start. Example: `/js/app.js`

Comment: Yes, they are each in their designated folder. Also, tried to place / at the start and that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: could you check the browser's console and let me know if it is showing any error.

Comment: It says:
index.html:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:63342/assignment-2--intro-to-internet-programming--cs-275--spring-2020/html/css/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: Issue was solved. Had to add "../" in front of the css and html links.